# angular2 - Updating a value based on its previous value

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to create a blog system that increments the amount of views a certain post has everytime the post is viewed. I'm using firebase for the database and when I go to retrieve the value of the post views, then update it, it continuously increments the value and freezes my browser.. Below is the code I have for it.. Any suggestions?

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './post.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.css']
})

export class Post {
    post: any;

    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase, router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute){
        route.params.forEach(p => {
            let id = p['id'];
            if(id != null){
                let views = 0;
                let postRef: AngularFireObject<any> = db.object('/Posts/'+id);
                this.post = postRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe(actions => {
                    this.post = actions.payload.val();
                    let v = this.post.views + 1;
                    postRef.update({
                        views: v
                    })
                });
            }else{
                router.navigate(['/']);
            }
        });  
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you initializing `this.post` with the subscription and later with the action payload ?

Comment: also your approach is very confusing. you are listening to the object's changes and then incrementing it, which again is going to trigger the change event and this keeps performing nested looping ....

Comment: You are checking for “id” in each parameter, should change that to “this.route.snapshot.params[‘id’], unless your first param is id, the current code will go into infinite loop

Comment: Ahhh lol wow thanbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working sample @ https://angular-5urevo.stackblitz.io/

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Subscription} from 'rxjs';

export class PostComponent implements OnDestroy  {
  post: any;  
  postRef: AngularFireObject<any>;
  postRefValueSub: Subscription;
  postRefUpdateSub: Subscription;

  constructor(protected db: AngularFireDatabase, protected router: Router, protected route: ActivatedRoute) {
    if(!this.route.snapshot.params['id']) {  
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      return;
    }

    this.postRef = db.object(`/posts/${this.route.snapshot.params['id']}`);
    /* updating post info to view ... */
    this.postRefValueSub = this.postRef.valueChanges().subscribe(value => this.post = value); 
    this.update();  
  }

  /* updating post views .... */
  update(value?: any){
    /* increment post's view and unsubscribe to prevent nested looping...  */
    this.postRefUpdateSub = this.postRefUpdateSub || this.postRef.valueChanges().subscribe((value) => {     
        this.postRefUpdateSub = this.unsubscribe(this.postRefUpdateSub);
        this.post = value || this.post || { views: 0 };
        this.post.views++;
        this.postRef.update(this.post);
    });
  }

  /* helper to unsubscribe from a subscription ...*/
  unsubscribe(subscription: Subscription) : Subscription {
    if(!subscription) { return subscription; }
    if(!subscription.closed) { subscription.unsubscribe(); } 
    return null;
  }

  /* unsubscribing from all subscriptions ... */
  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.postRefValueSub = this.unsubscribe(this.postRefValueSub);
    this.postRefUpdateSub = this.unsubscribe(this.postRefUpdateSub);
  }
}
```

Comment: Im going to try this soon!!

Comment: I expected the firbase subscription ot be based on page load,.. didnt account for the constant changes . Thans for your answer.

Comment: Yeah. Np. Little I could do.

Answer (score 0):

This may help for you:

Lets make views variable to global, so that everytime it can bind with your @template.

```
public views :number = 0;
```

and use it,

Comment: doesnt work, its a proble with the update being in the scope of the watcher